# How do I shave off a few mm from (part of) a mesh?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have a moderately complex mesh, part of which exactly touches another. I need to shave off a quarter of a mm so that the 3D print comes out right.

My initial idea: copy the faces in question, add thickness, subtract from original. This, however, leaves ugly ridges when a shaved and a non-shaved face meet at an obtuse angle:

[image: (Ridges)]

Secondary idea: select edge, do an individual extrusion. However, this leaves spikes at the corners because individual extrusion leaves the edges unconnected:

[image: individual extrusion]

… and also, when the geometry is more complex, selecting the edge in order to extrude it is a PITA.

The end result should probably look like this:

[image: proper edge geometry]

Thus, questions:

- is there a way to easily select the edge of a newly-thickened partial mesh?
- is there a way to do the individual extrusion so that the new edges stay connected (like in the third screenshot instead of the second)?
- Alternately, is there a better way to do what I want to do in the first place?

The file in question is [here](http://netz.smurf.noris.de/BorroTest.blend).

Comment: The bottom of your object is causing the biggest problem, I'm not sure how to solve, but look at the convergence!!!

Comment: Yeah, but that's just the sample. The real model is more convoluted.

Comment: It's an ugly method, and long + manual at that (And you might have snapping problems, but if your desperate it's probably worth a shot), I think you can do the solidify as you have done, then at every point that the Vertex lands inside the part, go to the vertex neighbor, then set your 3D Cursor there, and scale the "just inside" Vertex beyond the mesh. Then move that vert, via a slide and snap to the edge. Then repeat for each of these conditions. I have another unproven method that might be faster for this case, so I'll post it below this comment.

Comment: This is a little unproven (I will try to prove it after I write this up), but it popped into my head as I was writing the other and figured that you may get to trying it before I do. Try Selecting the perimeter ring of edges, and bevel them back 0.5mm. I think that could at least get you pointed into a direction that works albeit not very elegant. I hope it works for you.

Comment: The "real" object I'd like to use as a boundary is a bit more complex. Any solution that involves touching up each edge manually won't be feasible.